# How to fire multiple reactive forms validators using single submit button angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have two forms in single view, but have only one submit button. i want to fire validations in both forms with the submit button click without filling any data. 
Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can have Nested Reactive Form with FormGroups instead of multiple forms, then you can track all the controls with submit click. It will helps you to fire validations with form submit with single button click.